# Let A and B be countable sets. Is there any function f such that a certain condition holds for an uncountable number of functions g?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ and $B$ be countable infinite sets. Is there any function $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that the number of functions $g:B\rightarrow A$ with property that $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}$ but $f\circ g\neq\mathrm{id}$ are finite, countable infinite or uncountable infinite?

Comment: Yes. In fact each of the three possibilities can arise. (But one of them is kind of tricky).

Comment: Oops, the purported duplicate doesn't completely duplicate this question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is not injective, then there is no left inverese $g$ in the first place. Hence assuem $f$ injective.

If $f$ is onto, then there is no such $g$  because $f$ is bijective and the only left ionverese is also a right inverse.

If $f$ is  not onto, say $b\notin f(A)$, then $g\circ f=\operatorname{id}_A$ iff $g|{f(A)}$ is the unique inverse of the bijection $A\to f(A)$. On the other hand, certainly $f\circ g(b)\ne b$. This holds no matter what $g(b)$ is, thus giving us counatbly many $g$ (at least). 
More precisely, the set of such $g$ is in bijection with the set of maps $B\setminus f(B)\to A$ by mapping $h\colon B\setminus f(B)\to A$ to $g\colon B\to A$ with $g(b)=\begin{cases}f^{-1}(b)&\text{if $b\in f(A)$}\\h(b)&\text{if $b\notin f(A)$}\end{cases}$

Thus there are three possible cardinalities:

- $0$ if $f$ is onto
- $\aleph_0$ if $B\setminus f(A)$ is a finite nonempty set
- $2^{\aleph_0}$ if $B\setminus f(A)$ is a infinite